# Benefits of AJAX calls

Tags: ajax

I was preparing for the interview and I stumble across this question.

```
Can anyone explain me what are the Benefits of Ajax Calls,
why do we need Ajax Calls and what can be the disadvantages of Ajax.
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: way too broad of a question - I would start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, do you understand what AJAX is?  If not, I would start by reading through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29 .

One large benefit is that it allows for partial updates to pages, without requiring a reload of the current page or a load of a whole new page with each action or input, as was typical in years past.

One disadvantage may be some additional complexities, development time, and troubleshooting.  (The above Wikipedia link actually contains a list of 10 drawbacks for "disadvantages".)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will go through that...!!

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls can help you decrease website load. for example if you want to load a customers table from database ajax can load it in without refreshing your css and images etc... so you can save memory by using ajax.

disadvantage of ajax is ... it's taking too much time in development and little bit hard for basic users